# Swift closure conform to typealias including Any

Tags: swift

I have two typealias declarations

```
typealias QueryClosure = ((UInt?,UInt?)->([URLQueryItem])?)?
typealias SearchClosure = ((String?,UInt?)->([URLQueryItem])?)?
```

And I created closures for these

```
var queryFunc: (QueryClosure)? = ( {a,b in
    return [URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "\(a ?? defaultPageSize)"), URLQueryItem(name: "offset", value: "\( (b ?? defaultPageIndex) * (a ?? defaultPageSize) )")]
})

var searchFunc: (SearchClosure)? = ( {query,b in
    return [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query), URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "\(b ?? defaultPageIndex)")]
    }
)
```

Now I don't want to pass either a query or a search closure, I want to pass a general closure.

So I created a new typealias

```
typealias VariableClosure = ((Any?, Any?)->([URLQueryItem]))?
```

But I'm not able to convert to this type

```
let search : (VariableClosure) = ( {query,b in
    return [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query), URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "\(b ?? defaultPageIndex)")]
    }
)
```

This gives me the error that

```
Cannot convert value of type '(String?, _) -> [URLQueryItem]' to specified type 'VariableClosure' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<Any>, Optional<Any>) -> Array<URLQueryItem>>')
```

How can I create a closure (or better two) that conform to the typealias variableclosure, or in some other way have a kind of generic typealias that I can pass my closures to.

Comment: The type system is not supposed to work like this. What you are saying is that anyone can pass `Any`thing into the `VariableClosure` called `search`, but in actuality you are only accepting strings and ints.

Comment: @Sweeper - What is your suggestion? I want to have a general closure that can be passed around - any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `URLQueryItem` accepts a `String` and the `query` variable the you are passing is of `Any` type, you must first `typecast` `query` to `String` before using it.

Same goes for variable `b`. You must `typecast` it to `Int` before using.

```
let search: VariableClosure = {query,b in
    if let query = query as? Int, let b = b as? Int {
        return [URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "\(query ?? 10)"), URLQueryItem(name: "offset", value: "\( (b ?? 10) * (query ?? 10) )")]
    } else if let query = query as? String, let b = b as? Int {
        return [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query), URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "\(b ?? 1)")]
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the above case, if you are expecting `query` and `b` of other types as well, you must handle them manually.